# Media querys no funcionan correctamente en formato móvil

Tags: html, css

Tengo mi html maquetado por media querys de bootstrap pero he cambiado los min-width según me convenía a mi.

Si pruebo estos estilos en el ordenador funcionan correctamente y se ajustan como yo quiero. Pero a la hora de [probarlos en móvil](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) con chrome no me desplaza las columnas como debería.

Éste es css con las media querys

```
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.col, .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.col, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-xs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-12 {
  right: 100%;
}
.col-xs-pull-11 {
  right: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-10 {
  right: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-9 {
  right: 75%;
}
.col-xs-pull-8 {
  right: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-7 {
  right: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-6 {
  right: 50%;
}
.col-xs-pull-5 {
  right: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-4 {
  right: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-3 {
  right: 25%;
}
.col-xs-pull-2 {
  right: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-pull-1 {
  right: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-pull-0 {
  right: auto;
}
.col-xs-push-12 {
  left: 100%;
}
.col-xs-push-11 {
  left: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-10 {
  left: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-9 {
  left: 75%;
}
.col-xs-push-8 {
  left: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-7 {
  left: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-6 {
  left: 50%;
}
.col-xs-push-5 {
  left: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-4 {
  left: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-3 {
  left: 25%;
}
.col-xs-push-2 {
  left: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-push-1 {
  left: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-push-0 {
  left: auto;
}
.col-xs-offset-12 {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
.col-xs-offset-11 {
  margin-left: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-9 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}
.col-xs-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-7 {
  margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-6 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.col-xs-offset-5 {
  margin-left: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-4 {
  margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.col-xs-offset-2 {
  margin-left: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-0 {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
@media (min-width: 875px) {
  .col, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 972px) {
  .col, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-Indicadores {
    width: 28%;
  }
  .col-md-Labels {
    width: 72%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-md-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-md-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .col, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-lg-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

El html:

```
<div class="main-container" style="max-width:1050px;margin:auto;">          
        <div class="row">   <!-- Fila con botones zoom -->
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-7">      <!-- Columna botones zoom -->
                <div>
                    <button id="zoom_in">+</button>
                    <button id="zoom_out">-</button>        
                </div>
            </div> <!-- Fin columna botones zoom -->
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-5"></div><!-- Columna vacia para completar -->
        </div><!-- Fin fila botones zoom -->

        <div class="row"><!-- Fila con grafico e indicadores -->

            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-7"><!-- Columna grafico -->
                <div id="linegraph" ></div> 
            </div><!-- Fin columna grafico -->

            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-5 columnaIndicadores" ><!-- Columna indicadores -->
                <div class="controlesVelocidad" style="margin: 1em;padding:1em">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <span  class="titulo">Zona geográfica</span>
                            <a href="Informacion.html" target="_blank"><i style="float:right;padding-right:20px;color:blue;" class="pointer fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">                    
                            <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="selectZonas" onchange="selecionarTodasZonas();mostrarDatos();mostrarDatosLineas()"> Selecionar todas las zonas
                            </br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked" class="zona"  id="cae" onchange="mostrarDatos();mostrarDatosLineas()"> C.A.E
                            <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked" class="zona" id="araba" onchange="mostrarDatos();mostrarDatosLineas()"> Araba
                            <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked" class="zona" id="bizkaia" onchange="mostrarDatos();mostrarDatosLineas()"> Bizkaia
                            <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked" class="zona" id="gipuzkua" onchange="mostrarDatos();mostrarDatosLineas()"> Gipuzkua                       
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Fin row -->              
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <span class="titulo">Indicadores</span>                         
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="row">                                   
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">                           
                            <ul class="iconList" id="iconListx" >                           
                                <li style="padding-left:5px">C</li>
                                <li style="padding-left:5px">A</li>
                                <li style="padding-left:5px">B</li>
                                <li style="padding-left:5px">G</li>
                            </ul>                                               
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="selectAll" onchange="selecionarTodosIndicadores();mostrarDatos();mostrarDatosLineas()"> Selecionar todos los indicadores         
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Fin row -->          
                    <div id="contenedorIndicadores"></div>  <!-- Aqui van los indicadores (se cargan en un script) -->
                </div><!-- Fin bordes -->
            </div><!-- Fin columna indicadores-->               

        </div><!--Fin fila con grafico e indicadores -->




        <div class="row"><!-- Fila con columnas de control y grafico de lineas -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3" style="max-width:270px;min-width:220px;"><!-- Columna control play/pause/stop -->
                <span class="titulo">Animación</span>
                <div class="controlesVelocidad" style="margin:0 auto">
                    <button class="play">play</button>
                    <button class="pause" disabled>pause</button>
                    <button class="stop" disabled>stop</button>
                    </br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="repite" > Repetir    
                    </br>
                    <div id="sliderVelocidad"></div>                                                                
                </div>
            </div><!--Fin columna control play/pause/stop -->

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3" style="max-width:270px;min-width:220px;"><!-- Columna control cola/tiempo -->
                <span class="titulo">Control de cola y tiempo</span>
                <div class="controlesVelocidad">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="cola" > Cola     
                    </br>
                    <button id="masTamanio">+</button>
                    <button id="menosTamanio">-</button>
                    Tamaño cola         
                    <input style="width:35px" disabled value="1" type="numeric" name="tamanio_cola" id="tamanio_cola"/>
                    </br>
                    <label for="sliderFecha" style="width:100%;color:blue;">
                        <span id="slider-fecha-value-inicio" ></span>
                    </label>                        
                    <div id="sliderFecha"></div>
                </div>
            </div><!--Fin columna control cola/tiempo -->

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6" ><!-- Columna grafico lineas -->
                <div class="marginConMedia">
                    <span class="titulo">Desviación tipica de la tendencia del ciclo</span>
                    <div id="graficoLineas"></div>  
                    <div id="scrollLineas"></div>   
                </div>
            </div><!--Fin columna grafico lineas  -->
        </div><!--Fin filacon columnas de control y grafico de lineas -->
    <div>
```

En un principio si el ancho es menor de 875px la columna con los indicadores debería caer pero no lo hace.

[image]

Como veis el ancho del móvil no llega a pasa mucho mas de los 400 px por lo que la columna de la derecha (Columna indicadores en el html) debería caer y colocarse debajo del gráfico. Como digo esto solo me pasa en móviles.

Comment: ¿podrías poner un ejemplo **simplificado** de tu problema?

Comment: @AXL si supiera como simplificarlo aun mas lo haría, pero como puedo simplificar algo que no se donde falla? Las media querys estan bien, el html esta bien maquetado. A lo mejor se me escapa algo dentro del codigo, en ese caso, no debo mostrar mi codigo lo mas completo posible para que en vez de intentar simplificarlo y omitir el fallo que no se donde esta, alguien que entienda, o le haya pasado sepa decirme donde esta el error.

Comment: hombre, yo quería decir que pusieras un ejemplo simplificando todo se html. Tal vez bastaría con un grid de 2 columnas con las clases de bootstrap que tienes aplicadas y partiendo desde ahí veríamos si la 2ª columna no _cae_ o que le pasa, ¿me explico?

Comment: has puesto correctamente el viewport ? aqui tienes más información https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/M%C3%B3vil/Viewport_meta_tag
. ¿Puedes añadir el head de tu html para revisarlo?

Comment: @AngelFragaParodi pues no sabia ni que habia que ponerlo, ahora puesto ya funciona como deberia, muchas gracias, pon tu comentario como respuesta para que te lo acepte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es debido a que falta el  meta viewport en el head , este  le indica como debe comportarse en el dispositivo movil.
Este sería un viewport básico :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Tienes más información aquí, https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/M%C3%B3vil/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer el problema es que te has olvidado de indicarle al navegador que sea [`responsive` al ancho de la pantalla](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile).

### Solución:

Agrega esta etiqueta `meta` en el `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```